# offsetTop vs. jQuery.offset().top

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset

I have read that `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` do not work properly in all browsers.  `jQuery.offset()` is supposed to provide an abstraction for this to provide the correct value xbrowser.

What I am trying to do is get the coordinates of where an element was clicked relative to the top-left of the element.

Problem is that `jQuery.offset().top` is actually giving me a decimal value in FFX 3.6 (in IE and Chrome, the two values match).

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htCPp/) exhibits the issue.  If you click the bottom image, `jQuery.offset().top` returns 327.5, but `offsetTop` returns 328.

I would like to think that `offset()` is returning the correct value and I should use it because it will work across browsers.  However, people obviously cannot click decimals of pixels.  Is the proper way to determine the true offset to `Math.round()` the offset that jQuery is returning?  Should I use `offsetTop` instead, or some other method entirely?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you are right by saying that people cannot click half pixels, so personally, I would use rounded jQuery offset...

Comment: jQuery offset is buggy when CSS zoom is used

Answer (score 86):

This is what [jQuery API Doc](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) says about `.offset()`:

> Get the current coordinates of the first element, or set the
>   coordinates of every element, in the set of matched elements, relative
>   to the **document**.

This is what [MDN Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetTop) says about `.offsetTop`:

> offsetTop returns the distance of the current element relative to the
>   top of the **offsetParent node**

This is what jQuery v.1.11 `.offset()` basically do when getting the coords:

```
var box = { top: 0, left: 0 };

// BlackBerry 5, iOS 3 (original iPhone)
if ( typeof elem.getBoundingClientRect !== strundefined ) {
  box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
}
win = getWindow( doc );
return {
  top: box.top  + ( win.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop )  - ( docElem.clientTop  || 0 ),
  left: box.left + ( win.pageXOffset || docElem.scrollLeft ) - ( docElem.clientLeft || 0 )
};
```

- `pageYOffset` intuitively says how much was the page scrolled
- `docElem.scrollTop` is the fallback for IE<9 (which are BTW unsupported in jQuery 2)
- `docElem.clientTop` is the width of the top border of an element (the document in this case)
- `elem.getBoundingClientRect()` gets the coords relative to the <s>document</s> **viewport** (see comments). It may return fraction values, so this is the source of your bug. It also [may cause a bug in IE<8](http://help.dottoro.com/ljvmcrrn.php) when the page is zoomed. To avoid fraction values, try to calculate the position [iteratively](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html)

**Conclusion**

- If you want coords relative to the **parent node**, use `element.offsetTop`. Add `element.scrollTop` if you want to take the parent scrolling into account. (or use jQuery [.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) if you are fan of that library)
- If you want coords relative to the **viewport** use `element.getBoundingClientRect().top`. Add `window.pageYOffset` if you want to take the document scrolling into account. You don't need to subtract document's `clientTop` if the document has no border (usually it doesn't), so you have position relative to the **document**
- Subtract `element.clientTop` if you don't consider the element border as the part of the element

Comment: [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) gives positions relative to the *viewport*, not the document

Comment: @Klaus: could you explain what exactly is the difference?

Comment: @JanTuroň: The difference is that it is relative to the top of the browser window not the documents "true top". Meaning it will return negative values if you scroll it's top past the top of the window, for example.

Answer (score 5):

Try this: `parseInt(jQuery.offset().top, 10)`

Comment: I wish there was a reason behind it, so I could vote u up

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the `offset` could be a non-integer, using `em` as the measurement unit, relative `font-sizes` in `%`.

I also theorise that the `offset` might not be a whole number when the `zoom` isn't `100%` but that depends how the browser handles scaling.

Comment: if the zoom isnt 100%, offset().top will give you a plethora of other problems ... http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8362

Answer (score -1):

You can use `parseInt(jQuery.offset().top)` to always use the Integer (primitive - `int`) value across all browsers.

Comment: Does parseInt() round doubles or truncate them?

Comment: It will just take the integer part of the number and it will be same across all browser.

Comment: The OP states that in one browser it gives 327.5 where in another it gives 328. So if you just take the integer part (truncate) the OP itself is an example of it **not** being the same across all browsers. For this example at least it would have to round for both to give the same number.