# Can't create a reusable function for unchecking a radio button in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was given a requirement that all radio buttons across our site need to be unselectable.  I can manage to do this with a function hardcoded to that set of radio buttons.  But I would prefer to have a generic one so I don't have to add the same lines of code over and over.

Here's is my attempt to create a generic one.  It seems to almost work in that it detects when the radiobutton should be cleared (I logged in the console) but it does not actually clear anything.

```
$scope.RadioCheckUncheck = function (RadioModel, event) {
  if (RadioModel === event.target.value) {
    console.log('looks like you clicked this already')
    RadioModel = null;
  }
}
```

and HTML

```
ng-click="RadioCheckUncheck(myModelName, $event)"
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/HcMfXWTtIRT9WThxE3c5?p=preview

Here is a similar version that works, but it's hardcoded.

http://plnkr.co/edit/00XCKeiIJJeFj96yARjC?p=preview

Comment: What about $timeout(function() { $('.anycommonclass').attr('checked', false).trigger('change'); });

Comment: Well, here's [How to unselect a radio button](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10876953/4320665).  Then you'd just have to figure out a good way to make all the radio buttons unselectable.  I'd personally go with applying a custom attribute directive on specific radio inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `RadioCheckUncheck` method, the `RadioModel` parameter is just a string, not a reference to the `$scope` field, so setting it to `null` will not have the desired effect. You could instead pass the "key" to your `FavoriteThingies` dictionary and set it to `null` using that.

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="my_favorite" ng-value="'Tom'" ng-model="FavoriteThingies.FavoriteCharacter" ng-click="RadioCheckUncheck('FavoriteCharacter', $event)">Tom
<input type="radio" name="my_favorite" ng-value="'Jerry'" ng-model="FavoriteThingies.FavoriteCharacter" ng-click="RadioCheckUncheck('FavoriteCharacter', $event)">Jerry

<input type="radio" name="my_favorite_fruit" ng-value="'Orange'" ng-model="FavoriteThingies.FavoriteFruit" ng-click="RadioCheckUncheck('FavoriteFruit', $event)">Orange
<input type="radio" name="my_favorite_fruit" ng-value="'Apple'" ng-model="FavoriteThingies.FavoriteFruit" ng-click="RadioCheckUncheck('FavoriteFruit', $event)">Apple
```

JavaScript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('RadioController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.FavoriteThingies = {};
    $scope.RadioCheckUncheck = function (key, event) {
      if ($scope.FavoriteThingies[key] === event.target.value) {
        console.log('looks like you clicked this already')
        $scope.FavoriteThingies[key] = null;
      }
    }
});
```

An updated version is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/U0aQEfe6WBTfsu8MPsBQ?p=info.

Comment: Was just going to post the same thing.  Your answer is more concise, so I am glad I didn't.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Seems so obvious now.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do in your case is create a directive for this (won't get anything more reusable than this)

Something like

```
myApp.directive('uncheckable', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      val: '=ngModel'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      element.bind('click', function(){
        if(scope.val) scope.val = null;
      })
    }
  }
})
```

and then just use it like:

```
<input uncheckable type="radio" name="Tom" ng-value="'Tom'" ng-model="myModel" />
```

Here is a plnkr 
http://plnkr.co/edit/Ts2a6z3zbEyjlbXzaAYC?p=preview

You can even be more elaborate playing with ngModelController instead of binding to ngModel (which has the exact same effect, but is more powerful) by doing something like:

```
myApp.directive('uncheckable', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
      if(!ngModelController) return; //do nothing if not binded
      element.bind('click', function() {
        if (ngModelController.$modelValue) {
          ngModelController.$setViewValue(null);
          ngModelController.$render();
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

check it here http://plnkr.co/edit/IrvfZq?p=preview

Comment: This is certainly the more Angular (and cleaner, more modular) approach.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want a directive, so you can easily re-use this functionality. I've updated the plunkr here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/yQv4vZwX1Tf2uhPy7Kff?p=preview

... but here's the meat for convenience:

```
myApp.directive('unselectable', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      clickCount = 0;
      element.on('click', function() {
        clickCount++;
        if (element[0].checked && clickCount > 1) {
          element[0].checked = false;
          clickCount = 0;
        }
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

Then just add the directive to the radio elements:

```
<input unselectable type="radio" name="my_favorite" ng-value="'Tom'" ng-model="FavoriteThingies.FavoriteCharacter">
```