# How to clear a checked radiobutton in a radiobutton group upon click on the same checked radiobutton

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, html

I have 2 radiobutton group.

1) containing two radiobuttons 
2) containing an array of radiobuttongroup each group containing 3 radiobuttons

I want to clear the checked radiobutton upon click on the same radio button without using an extra button for clearing.

I need javascript code since reactJS not supporting jQuery
Please help me to resolve this problem.. I am very new to reactJS programming world.

Comment: Please provide the sample code you have written for this

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876953/how-to-make-a-radio-button-unchecked-by-clicking-it) might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I have created one sample this may help for you

demo in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kbdr85)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      group1:[{"value":"1"},
      {"value":"2"},
      {"value":"3"}],
      group1Selected:null,
      group2:[{"value":"1"},
      {"value":"2"},
      {"value":"3"}],
       group2Selected:null,
    };
  }
  ChangeOption = (i,group) =>{
    var groupData = this.state[group] == i?null:i;        
    this.setState({[group]:groupData})
  }
  render() {
    const {group1,group2,group1Selected,group2Selected} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {
          group1.map( (data,i)=><><input type="radio" id={`1-${i}`} onClick={e=>this.ChangeOption(i,"group1Selected")} checked={i==group1Selected?true:false} name="1" value={data.value}/><label for={`1-${i}`}>{data.value}</label></>)
        }
        <br/>
        {
          group2.map( (data,i)=><><input id={`2-${i}`} onClick={e=>this.ChangeOption(i,"group2Selected")} type="radio" checked={i==group2Selected?true:false} name="2" value={data.value}/><label for={`2-${i}`}>{data.value}</label></>)
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```