# How can I uncheck a checked radio input by click on its label?

Tags: javascript, queryselector

### This is the code

> I have a group of hidden radio inputs with the same name

```
    <input name="megamenu" type="radio" id="menu-1" hidden>
    <label class="nav-link" for="menu-1">menu1</label>
    
    <input name="megamenu" type="radio" id="menu-2" hidden>
    <label class="nav-link" for="menu-2">menu2</label>
    
    <input name="megamenu" type="radio" id="menu-3" hidden>
    <label class="nav-link" for="menu-3">menu3</label>
```

When I click on each label they get checked. How can I uncheck a checked radio input by click on its label?

### My attempt

```
    if (document.querySelector('input[name="megamenu"]:checked')) {
      document.querySelectorAll('input[name="megamenu"]:checked').forEach((elem) => {
        elem.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    
          event.target.checked = false;
    
        });
      });
    }
```

### I also tried this

```
    var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="megamenu"]:checked');
    for(i=0; i<radios.length; i++ ) {
        radios[i].onclick = function(e) {
            if(e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
                this.checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why (mis)use radio-buttons? Why not use check-boxes?

Comment: you can easily acheive this by using chek box instead of radio button

Comment: I found these methods below worked, check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876953/how-to-make-a-radio-button-unchecked-by-clicking-it/10877016)

Comment: @enhzflep I use it for CSS menu selector. with checkbox, I must uncheck all of the other checkboxes again

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is by using the `.checked` JS property, like in the following snippet:

```js
let label = document.getElementById('label-id');
let radioBTN = document.getElementById('radio-id');

label.addEventListener('click', function(){ radioBTN.checked = false })
```

```html
<input id='radio-id' type='radio' checked/>  <br><br>

<label id="label-id" style='cursor:pointer'>
  Click this label to uncheck the radio button
</label>
```

For more info click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_radio_checked.asp)