# scrollpath.js getting top value

Tags: javascript, jquery, path, scroll

How do I get following top value?

```
<div class="sp-scroll-handle" style="top: 1.0416666666666665px; "> </div>
```

this value is getting creating by some javascript, i think its following:

```
function dragScrollHandler( e ) {
        var dragStep,
            y = e.clientY - scrollBar.offset().top;

        dragStep = limitWithin( Math.round( y / scrollBar.height() * ( pathList.length - 1 ) ), 0, pathList.length - 1 );

        scrollToStep( snap(dragStep, STEP_SIZE) );
    }
```

now i need this value, I tried this:

```
$('.sp-scroll-handle').scroll(function () {

    var top_value = $('.sp-scroll-handle').css("top");
    $('.settings b').text(top_value);}
});
```

but it does not work - any clue?

Comment: This post may be informative [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777506/offsettop-vs-jquery-offset-top)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are selecting a class try looping through like this:

```
$('.sp-scroll-handle').each(function(i) {
  if(i=0){ 
    //assuming you want the first .sp-scroll-handle top value
    $('.settings b').text($(this).css('top'));
  }
});
```

`offset.top` may also help you get what you need. [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Per your comment, I suggest you read documentation on [scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/). This seems to be the value you are looking for and it is not the same as the CSS `top` value.

Comment: i actually need "every" top value - i want to achieve this: http://jsbin.com/exoyab/1/edit but in scrollpath.js the body does not scrollpath the body does not scroll but this handle which actually got a top value...i try it with offset.top right now

Comment: Your example is using `.scrollTop` which gets the current vertical position of the scroll bar for the selected element. Then it checks to see if the value of .scrollTop() is above 409, about mid page, and if it is, fade the element to 100%. See documentation link in my answer.

Comment: i get this but .scrollTop does only work with the regular scroll bar right? but i dont have the regular scrollbar

Comment: this is basically my code: http://joelb.me/scrollpath/  now i need this fadin in to get working with this scroll bar