# jQuery error Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`

Tags: jquery

I need to detect scroll direction on `mouseenter` on certain div so I try to use code below

```
$.fn.scroll = function () {
var $this = $(this);
var $list = $(this).find('ul');
var $lis = $list.find('li');
var direction;

$this.addClass('scroll');
$list.addClass('slides-list');
$lis.addClass('slide');
$lis.filter(':first').addClass('current');
$lis.filter(':not(:first)').addClass('past');

$this.on('mouseenter', function(){

    var lastScrollTop = $this.offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($this.hasClass('animated')) {
            return;
        }

        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop) {
            direction = 'down';
        } else {
            direction = 'up';
        }

        lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
    });

});
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#scroll').scroll();
});
```

but in line
`var lastScrollTop = $this.offset().top;`
I get an error
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`.

I guess I have some problem with scopes, but I don't know how to fix it?

Comment: Have you done a `console.log($this)` to see what you're trying to call `.offset()` on?

Comment: It tries to call `.offset()` on `Window`

Comment: That'll be why - window isn't an element and therefore doesn't have the `offsetTop` property, maybe you're after `$this.scrollTop()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this readonly property:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop

And check this question as well

[offsetTop vs. jQuery.offset().top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777506/offsettop-vs-jquery-offset-top)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#scroll').bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
    console.log('Scroll up');
}else {
    console.log('Scroll down');
}});
```

More on [How can I determine the direction of a jQuery scroll event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing $this with $(this) or $("#scroll") it works