# How can I identify the view div section I have scrolled to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website with 4 divs that all have heights of 100vh that fill the entire view height and view width. But I can't seem to figure out the section of the div I have navigated to. Is there a way I can use

```
$(this).scrollTop()
```

to find out the view or div I am currently viewing? I know this question is quite confusing but if you understand what I am getting at, I truly need your help.

Comment: Are you trying to have 4 different " pages " as divs? in that case put an id on each of the divs and show / hide the others when displaying one of them

Comment: You can take a look at how some libraries with a similar behavior do it.
Take a look at [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) and its  [source code](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/jquery.fullPage.js#L954).

Answer (score 2):

Basically, in your case, you have to know how much have you scrolled the page.

```
var scrolledY = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
```

After that, as long as your divs have height of `100vh` it is the same as `window.innerHeight`. Therefore, you can calculate the index of div you scrolled to:

```
var divIdx = Math.floor(scrolledY / vh);
```

Now, all together: http://jsbin.com/qepodojoqa/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind an event to `scroll` and check if you scrolled past a div's top offset.

```
$(document).scrollTop()
```

gives you your current top scroll, and

```
element.offsetTop
```

gives you the div's offset from the top (i.e, the distance between its top and the top of its parent node, body in this case).

Be aware that there are [other ways to detect the top scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777506/offsettop-vs-jquery-offset-top), depending on your needs.