# Navigate to a section of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a static page and navigating to the sections using id and href reference. Upon selecting a section the scroll does't slides in to the beginning of the section. It's hiding the label part of the section. Can someone help me with this. Couple of the images in the page aren't working please ignore them.

```js
var menuObject = document.getElementById("open-menu");
menuObject.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var asideObject = document.getElementById('offcanvas');
  asideObject.classList.add('open');
})
var closeBtn = document.getElementById('close-btn');
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var asideObject = document.getElementById('offcanvas');
  asideObject.classList.remove('open');
  event.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:active,
a:focus,
a:hover,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Lato";
  src: url('./assets/fonts/lato-regular.eot');
  src: url('./assets/fonts/lato-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('./assets/fonts/lato-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('./assets/fonts/lato-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('./assets/fonts/lato-regular.svg#Lato') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Bitter';
  src: url('./assets/fonts/Bitter-Regular.eot');
  src: url('./assets/fonts/Bitter-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('./assets/fonts/Bitter-Regular.ttf') format('ttf'), url('./assets/fonts/Bitter-Regular.svg') format('svg');
}
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  color: #36384c;
  background-color: #e9dccd;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 7.5rem;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 2.125rem;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 1.875rem;
}
.app-header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.121rem;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #36384c;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  z-index: 1;
}
.app-header .header-wrapper {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.app-header .header-wrapper .brand-logo {
  display: inline-block;
  color: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
}
.app-header .header-wrapper .brand-logo img {
  height: 100%;
}
.app-header .header-wrapper .header-nav {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.app-header .header-wrapper .header-nav > a {
  color: inherit;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.app-header .header-wrapper .open-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  width: 55px;
  top: 16px;
  padding: 12px;
}
.app-header .header-wrapper .open-menu span {
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
aside {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 1.121rem;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #36384c;
}
aside.open {
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
}
aside .offcanvas-content {
  margin-top: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}
aside .close-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 44px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
aside .close-btn span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
aside .close-btn span:first-child {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
aside .close-btn span:last-child {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}
aside .offcanvas-item {
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
  line-height: 2;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
main {
  padding-top: 80px;
}
#Main {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('./assets/images/coffee.jpg');
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#Main.container {
  max-width: none;
}
#Main .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#Main .full-width {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -2rem;
}
#Main .full-width h1 {
  font-family: Bitter, serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0 0 16px;
}
#Main .full-width h2 {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  min-height: 600px;
  padding: 40px 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.block-wrapper:nth-child(odd) {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #36384c;
}
#About p {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  line-height: 1.8;
}
#About .grid-row div.image-bg {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}
#About .grid-row div.image-bg:first-child {
  background-image: url('./assets/images/coffee-grid.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
#About .grid-row div.image-bg:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url('./assets/images/people.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
#About .grid-row div.image-bg:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url('./assets/images/coffee-grid3.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
#About .grid-row div.image-bg:last-child {
  background-image: url('./assets/images/blackcoffee.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
#Menu .grid-row {
  text-align: center;
}
#Menu .grid-row img {
  width: 100%;
}
#Location .grid-row {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#Location .grid-row .grid-item {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
#Location .grid-row .grid-item img {
  width: 460px;
}
.block-content.text {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  padding: 1.5rem 0;
  line-height: 1.8;
}
footer {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #36384c;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 655px) {
  main {
    padding-top: 100px;
  }
  .app-header .header-wrapper .brand-logo {
    height: 80px;
  }
  .app-header .header-wrapper .header-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding: 32px 0;
  }
  .app-header .header-wrapper .open-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  aside {
    display: none;
  }
  #Main .full-width {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  }
  #About .grid-row div.image-bg {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 21%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-right: 12px;
  }
  #Menu .grid-item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48%;
  }
  #Menu .grid-item:nth-child(odd) {
    float: right;
  }
  #Location .grid-row .grid-item {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
  }
  #Location .grid-row .grid-item img {
    width: auto;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 655px) and (max-width: 990px) {
  #About .grid-row div.image-bg {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 46%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 990px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
  
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 665px) {
  #Main.container {
    min-height: auto;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .block-content.text {
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="app-header">
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <a class="brand-logo" href="#Main">
      <img src="./assets/images/logo-central-coffee.png"></a>
    <nav class="header-nav">
      <a href="#About">About</a>
      <a href="#Menu">Menu</a>
      <a href="#Location">Location</a>
    </nav>
    <a id="open-menu" class="open-menu" href="#">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
<aside id="offcanvas" class="offcanvas">
  <div class="offcanvas-content">
    <a id="close-btn" class="close-btn" href="">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </a>
    <a class="offcanvas-item" href="#About">About</a>
    <a class="offcanvas-item" href="#Menu">Menu</a>
    <a class="offcanvas-item" href="#Location">Location</a>
  </div>
</aside>
<main>
  <section id="Main" class="container">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="full-width">
      <hgroup>
        <h1>Central Coffee</h1>
        <h3>Bespoke organically-sourced coffee</h3>
      </hgroup>
    </div>

  </section>
  <section id="About" class="block-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="block-content text">
        <h2>About</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis sagittis urna, a fermentum mauris. Mauris sagittis eu urna at sollicitudin. Sed et dui accumsan, vulputate dui ut, fringilla tellus. Vivamus a ex commodo, vulputate metus gravida,
          congue arcu. Fusce vehicula laoreet lorem vel lacinia. Etiam ac erat turpis. Morbi nec urna aliquet, placerat nisl ac, venenatis justo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </p>
        <div class="grid-row">
          <div class="image-bg"></div>
          <div class="image-bg"></div>
          <div class="image-bg"></div>
          <div class="image-bg"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="Menu" class="block-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="block-content text">
        <h2>Menu</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis sagittis urna, a fermentum mauris. Mauris sagittis eu urna at sollicitudin. Sed et dui accumsan, vulputate dui ut, fringilla tellus. Vivamus a ex commodo, vulputate metus gravida,
          congue arcu. Fusce vehicula laoreet lorem vel lacinia. Etiam ac erat turpis. Morbi nec urna aliquet, placerat nisl ac, venenatis justo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <div class="grid-row">
          <div class="grid-item">
            <header>DRINKS</header>
            <img src="./assets/images/food-3249174_640.jpg">
            <div>
              <p>La Catalina (Colombia)</p>
              <p>Guarumales (Ecuador)</p>
              <p>Rukondo (Rwanda)</p>
              <p>Peppermint Tea</p>
              <p>Black tea</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-item">
            <header>FOOD</header>
            <img src="./assets/images/coffee-3297326_640.jpg">
            <div>
              <p>Frittata (Herb and Veggie, Italian, Corned Beef)</p>
              <p>Breakfast sandwich</p>
              <p>Cobb salad</p>
              <p>Various baked goods</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="Location" class="block-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="block-content text">
        <h2>Location</h2>
        <div class="grid-row">
          <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="./assets/images/map.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="grid-item">
            <header>Hours</header>
            <p>Mon-Thurs -- 7am - 8pm</p>
            <p>Fri-Sun -- 8am - 10pm</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
<footer> @2018 Central Coffee</footer>
```

Comment: Take a look at jQuery Offset -
 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777506/offsettop-vs-jquery-offset-top)

Answer (score 0):

You can add some padding to every section as this :

```js
var menuObject = document.getElementById("open-menu");
menuObject.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var asideObject = document.getElementById('offcanvas');
  asideObject.classList.add('open');
})
var closeBtn = document.getElementById('close-btn');
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var asideObject = document.getElementById('offcanvas');
  asideObject.classList.remove('open');
  event.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:active,
a:focus,
a:hover,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Lato";
  src: url('./assets/fonts/lato-regular.eot');
  src: url('./assets/fonts/lato-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('./assets/fonts/lato-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('./assets/fonts/lato-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('./assets/fonts/lato-regular.svg#Lato') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Bitter';
  src: url('./assets/fonts/Bitter-Regular.eot');
  src: url('./assets/fonts/Bitter-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('./assets/fonts/Bitter-Regular.ttf') format('ttf'), url('./assets/fonts/Bitter-Regular.svg') format('svg');
}
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  color: #36384c;
  background-color: #e9dccd;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 7.5rem;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 2.125rem;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 1.875rem;
}
.app-header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.121rem;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #36384c;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  z-index: 1;
}
.app-header .header-wrapper {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.app-header .header-wrapper .brand-logo {
  display: inline-block;
  color: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
}
.app-header .header-wrapper .brand-logo img {
  height: 100%;
}
.app-header .header-wrapper .header-nav {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.app-header .header-wrapper .header-nav > a {
  color: inherit;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.app-header .header-wrapper .open-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  width: 55px;
  top: 16px;
  padding: 12px;
}
.app-header .header-wrapper .open-menu span {
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
aside {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 1.121rem;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #36384c;
}
aside.open {
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
}
aside .offcanvas-content {
  margin-top: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}
aside .close-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 44px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
aside .close-btn span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
aside .close-btn span:first-child {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
aside .close-btn span:last-child {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}
aside .offcanvas-item {
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
  line-height: 2;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
main {
  padding-top: 80px;
}
#Main {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('./assets/images/coffee.jpg');
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#Main.container {
  max-width: none;
}
#Main .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#Main .full-width {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -2rem;
}
#Main .full-width h1 {
  font-family: Bitter, serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0 0 16px;
}
#Main .full-width h2 {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  min-height: 600px;
  padding: 40px 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.block-wrapper:nth-child(odd) {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #36384c;
}
#About p {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  line-height: 1.8;
}
#About .grid-row div.image-bg {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}
#About .grid-row div.image-bg:first-child {
  background-image: url('./assets/images/coffee-grid.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
#About .grid-row div.image-bg:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url('./assets/images/people.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
#About .grid-row div.image-bg:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url('./assets/images/coffee-grid3.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
#About .grid-row div.image-bg:last-child {
  background-image: url('./assets/images/blackcoffee.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
#Menu .grid-row {
  text-align: center;
}
#Menu .grid-row img {
  width: 100%;
}
#Location .grid-row {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#Location .grid-row .grid-item {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
#Location .grid-row .grid-item img {
  width: 460px;
}
.block-content.text {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  padding: 1.5rem 0;
  line-height: 1.8;
}
footer {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #36384c;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 655px) {
  main {
    padding-top: 100px;
  }
  .app-header .header-wrapper .brand-logo {
    height: 80px;
  }
  .app-header .header-wrapper .header-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding: 32px 0;
  }
  .app-header .header-wrapper .open-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  aside {
    display: none;
  }
  #Main .full-width {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  }
  #About .grid-row div.image-bg {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 21%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-right: 12px;
  }
  #Menu .grid-item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48%;
  }
  #Menu .grid-item:nth-child(odd) {
    float: right;
  }
  #Location .grid-row .grid-item {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
  }
  #Location .grid-row .grid-item img {
    width: auto;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 655px) and (max-width: 990px) {
  #About .grid-row div.image-bg {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 46%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 990px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
  
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 665px) {
  #Main.container {
    min-height: auto;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .block-content.text {
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
section {
  padding:50px 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="app-header">
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <a class="brand-logo" href="#Main">
      <img src="./assets/images/logo-central-coffee.png"></a>
    <nav class="header-nav">
      <a href="#About">About</a>
      <a href="#Menu">Menu</a>
      <a href="#Location">Location</a>
    </nav>
    <a id="open-menu" class="open-menu" href="#">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
<aside id="offcanvas" class="offcanvas">
  <div class="offcanvas-content">
    <a id="close-btn" class="close-btn" href="">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </a>
    <a class="offcanvas-item" href="#About">About</a>
    <a class="offcanvas-item" href="#Menu">Menu</a>
    <a class="offcanvas-item" href="#Location">Location</a>
  </div>
</aside>
<main>
  <section id="Main" class="container">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="full-width">
      <hgroup>
        <h1>Central Coffee</h1>
        <h3>Bespoke organically-sourced coffee</h3>
      </hgroup>
    </div>

  </section>
  <section id="About" class="block-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="block-content text">
        <h2>About</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis sagittis urna, a fermentum mauris. Mauris sagittis eu urna at sollicitudin. Sed et dui accumsan, vulputate dui ut, fringilla tellus. Vivamus a ex commodo, vulputate metus gravida,
          congue arcu. Fusce vehicula laoreet lorem vel lacinia. Etiam ac erat turpis. Morbi nec urna aliquet, placerat nisl ac, venenatis justo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </p>
        <div class="grid-row">
          <div class="image-bg"></div>
          <div class="image-bg"></div>
          <div class="image-bg"></div>
          <div class="image-bg"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="Menu" class="block-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="block-content text">
        <h2>Menu</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis sagittis urna, a fermentum mauris. Mauris sagittis eu urna at sollicitudin. Sed et dui accumsan, vulputate dui ut, fringilla tellus. Vivamus a ex commodo, vulputate metus gravida,
          congue arcu. Fusce vehicula laoreet lorem vel lacinia. Etiam ac erat turpis. Morbi nec urna aliquet, placerat nisl ac, venenatis justo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <div class="grid-row">
          <div class="grid-item">
            <header>DRINKS</header>
            <img src="./assets/images/food-3249174_640.jpg">
            <div>
              <p>La Catalina (Colombia)</p>
              <p>Guarumales (Ecuador)</p>
              <p>Rukondo (Rwanda)</p>
              <p>Peppermint Tea</p>
              <p>Black tea</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-item">
            <header>FOOD</header>
            <img src="./assets/images/coffee-3297326_640.jpg">
            <div>
              <p>Frittata (Herb and Veggie, Italian, Corned Beef)</p>
              <p>Breakfast sandwich</p>
              <p>Cobb salad</p>
              <p>Various baked goods</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="Location" class="block-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="block-content text">
        <h2>Location</h2>
        <div class="grid-row">
          <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="./assets/images/map.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="grid-item">
            <header>Hours</header>
            <p>Mon-Thurs -- 7am - 8pm</p>
            <p>Fri-Sun -- 8am - 10pm</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
<footer> @2018 Central Coffee</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a top margin to the `.block-content.text` class. It will lower the div content and display the title of that section.

```js
var menuObject = document.getElementById("open-menu");
menuObject.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var asideObject = document.getElementById('offcanvas');
  asideObject.classList.add('open');
})
var closeBtn = document.getElementById('close-btn');
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var asideObject = document.getElementById('offcanvas');
  asideObject.classList.remove('open');
  event.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:active,
a:focus,
a:hover,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Lato";
  src: url('./assets/fonts/lato-regular.eot');
  src: url('./assets/fonts/lato-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('./assets/fonts/lato-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('./assets/fonts/lato-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('./assets/fonts/lato-regular.svg#Lato') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Bitter';
  src: url('./assets/fonts/Bitter-Regular.eot');
  src: url('./assets/fonts/Bitter-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('./assets/fonts/Bitter-Regular.ttf') format('ttf'), url('./assets/fonts/Bitter-Regular.svg') format('svg');
}
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  color: #36384c;
  background-color: #e9dccd;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 7.5rem;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 2.125rem;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 1.875rem;
}
.app-header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.121rem;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #36384c;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  z-index: 1;
}
.app-header .header-wrapper {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.app-header .header-wrapper .brand-logo {
  display: inline-block;
  color: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
}
.app-header .header-wrapper .brand-logo img {
  height: 100%;
}
.app-header .header-wrapper .header-nav {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.app-header .header-wrapper .header-nav > a {
  color: inherit;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.app-header .header-wrapper .open-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  width: 55px;
  top: 16px;
  padding: 12px;
}
.app-header .header-wrapper .open-menu span {
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
aside {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 1.121rem;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #36384c;
}
aside.open {
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
}
aside .offcanvas-content {
  margin-top: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}
aside .close-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 44px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
aside .close-btn span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
aside .close-btn span:first-child {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
aside .close-btn span:last-child {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}
aside .offcanvas-item {
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
  line-height: 2;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
main {
  padding-top: 80px;
}
#Main {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('./assets/images/coffee.jpg');
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#Main.container {
  max-width: none;
}
#Main .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#Main .full-width {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -2rem;
}
#Main .full-width h1 {
  font-family: Bitter, serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0 0 16px;
}
#Main .full-width h2 {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  min-height: 600px;
  padding: 40px 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.block-wrapper:nth-child(odd) {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #36384c;
}
#About p {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  line-height: 1.8;
}
#About .grid-row div.image-bg {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}
#About .grid-row div.image-bg:first-child {
  background-image: url('./assets/images/coffee-grid.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
#About .grid-row div.image-bg:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url('./assets/images/people.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
#About .grid-row div.image-bg:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url('./assets/images/coffee-grid3.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
#About .grid-row div.image-bg:last-child {
  background-image: url('./assets/images/blackcoffee.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
#Menu .grid-row {
  text-align: center;
}
#Menu .grid-row img {
  width: 100%;
}
#Location .grid-row {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#Location .grid-row .grid-item {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
#Location .grid-row .grid-item img {
  width: 460px;
}
.block-content.text {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  padding: 1.5rem 0;
  line-height: 1.8;
  margin-top: 45px;
}
footer {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #36384c;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 655px) {
  main {
    padding-top: 100px;
  }
  .app-header .header-wrapper .brand-logo {
    height: 80px;
  }
  .app-header .header-wrapper .header-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding: 32px 0;
  }
  .app-header .header-wrapper .open-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  aside {
    display: none;
  }
  #Main .full-width {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  }
  #About .grid-row div.image-bg {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 21%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-right: 12px;
  }
  #Menu .grid-item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48%;
  }
  #Menu .grid-item:nth-child(odd) {
    float: right;
  }
  #Location .grid-row .grid-item {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
  }
  #Location .grid-row .grid-item img {
    width: auto;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 655px) and (max-width: 990px) {
  #About .grid-row div.image-bg {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 46%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 990px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
  
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 665px) {
  #Main.container {
    min-height: auto;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .block-content.text {
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;

  }
}
```

```html
<header class="app-header">
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <a class="brand-logo" href="#Main">
      <img src="./assets/images/logo-central-coffee.png"></a>
    <nav class="header-nav">
      <a href="#About">About</a>
      <a href="#Menu">Menu</a>
      <a href="#Location">Location</a>
    </nav>
    <a id="open-menu" class="open-menu" href="#">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
<aside id="offcanvas" class="offcanvas">
  <div class="offcanvas-content">
    <a id="close-btn" class="close-btn" href="">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </a>
    <a class="offcanvas-item" href="#About">About</a>
    <a class="offcanvas-item" href="#Menu">Menu</a>
    <a class="offcanvas-item" href="#Location">Location</a>
  </div>
</aside>
<main>
  <section id="Main" class="container">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="full-width">
      <hgroup>
        <h1>Central Coffee</h1>
        <h3>Bespoke organically-sourced coffee</h3>
      </hgroup>
    </div>

  </section>
  <section id="About" class="block-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="block-content text">
        <h2>About</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis sagittis urna, a fermentum mauris. Mauris sagittis eu urna at sollicitudin. Sed et dui accumsan, vulputate dui ut, fringilla tellus. Vivamus a ex commodo, vulputate metus gravida,
          congue arcu. Fusce vehicula laoreet lorem vel lacinia. Etiam ac erat turpis. Morbi nec urna aliquet, placerat nisl ac, venenatis justo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </p>
        <div class="grid-row">
          <div class="image-bg"></div>
          <div class="image-bg"></div>
          <div class="image-bg"></div>
          <div class="image-bg"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="Menu" class="block-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="block-content text">
        <h2>Menu</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis sagittis urna, a fermentum mauris. Mauris sagittis eu urna at sollicitudin. Sed et dui accumsan, vulputate dui ut, fringilla tellus. Vivamus a ex commodo, vulputate metus gravida,
          congue arcu. Fusce vehicula laoreet lorem vel lacinia. Etiam ac erat turpis. Morbi nec urna aliquet, placerat nisl ac, venenatis justo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <div class="grid-row">
          <div class="grid-item">
            <header>DRINKS</header>
            <img src="./assets/images/food-3249174_640.jpg">
            <div>
              <p>La Catalina (Colombia)</p>
              <p>Guarumales (Ecuador)</p>
              <p>Rukondo (Rwanda)</p>
              <p>Peppermint Tea</p>
              <p>Black tea</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-item">
            <header>FOOD</header>
            <img src="./assets/images/coffee-3297326_640.jpg">
            <div>
              <p>Frittata (Herb and Veggie, Italian, Corned Beef)</p>
              <p>Breakfast sandwich</p>
              <p>Cobb salad</p>
              <p>Various baked goods</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="Location" class="block-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="block-content text">
        <h2>Location</h2>
        <div class="grid-row">
          <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="./assets/images/map.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="grid-item">
            <header>Hours</header>
            <p>Mon-Thurs -- 7am - 8pm</p>
            <p>Fri-Sun -- 8am - 10pm</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
<footer> @2018 Central Coffee</footer>
```