# Check if var exists in JavaScript to avoid undefined .top error

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my homepage, I have a video module and the following JS below animated in those `cards`.

All my JS minifies, so, when going on to a page that doesn't have this module, I get `Cannot read property 'top' of undefined` errors.

To prevent that, I'm trying to check if the variable exists before executing the script, but it doesn't work. Why doesn't the following work:

```js
var scrolled = false;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    scrolled = true;
});



function loadCards() {
    if (scrolled) {
      var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

      if(wScroll > $('.vidCard').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.5)) {

       $('.vidCard').each(function(i){

         setTimeout(function(){
           $('.vidCard' ).eq(i).addClass('is-showing');
         }, 150 * (i+1));
       });

      }
    }

}


$(window).scroll(function() {
  loadCards();
});

$(function() {
  loadCards();
});
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious place where you check for non-null.

Comment: what is `$('.vidCard')` selector returning?

Comment: Also, the message means that `$('.vidCard').offset()` returns `undefined`, not any particular variable. Thus minification will have no effect on this. Most likely that selector doesn't match anything.

Comment: why do have two

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    scrolled = true;
});

and 

$(window).scroll(function() {
  loadCards();
});

instead you can have one 

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    scrolled = true;
    loadCards();
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `this` keyword you use in `var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();` is cause the problem. If you want the *scrollTop* of any element, write the selector of element (I think in here it is **window**). Also if you want to make it work for the first time, then you should write another algorithm that *scrolled* variable is not **false** there for very first time.

But I look at snippet below:

**A brief description:**
We have a function **isVisible** that detect if an element is visible in just window section (not above it and neither below). Also each scroll, limit the search area with selecting `vidCard`s that are not have `is-showing` class (by using this approach, detection will be faster and the animation will be smooth and not take a long time to show!). I assumed that `is-showing` have opacity effect.

I hope it helps :)

```js
function isVisible(el) {
  var $el = $(el),
    above = $el.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() + $el.outerHeight() < 0,
    below = $el.offset().top > $(window).outerHeight() + $(window).scrollTop();
  return !above && !below;
}

function loadCards() {
  $('.vidCard:not(.is-showing)').each(function(i) {
    var card = $(this);

    if (isVisible(card) && !card.hasClass('is-showing')) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        card.addClass('is-showing');
      }, 150 * (i + 1));
    }
  });
}

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  loadCards();
});

loadCards();
```

```css
.vidCard {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.is-showing {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: all ease 0.6s;
  -ms-transition: all ease 0.6s;
  -o-transition: all ease 0.6s;
  transition: all ease 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vidCard"></div>
<div class="vidCard"></div>
<div class="vidCard"></div>
<div class="vidCard"></div>
<div class="vidCard"></div>
<div class="vidCard"></div>
<div class="vidCard"></div>
<div class="vidCard"></div>
<div class="vidCard"></div>
<div class="vidCard"></div>
<div class="vidCard"></div>
<div class="vidCard"></div>
<div class="vidCard"></div>
<div class="vidCard"></div>
<div class="vidCard"></div>
<div class="vidCard"></div>
<div class="vidCard"></div>
<div class="vidCard"></div>
<div class="vidCard"></div>
<div class="vidCard"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use offsetTop instead of .offset().top

This answer can help you: [offsetTop vs. jQuery.offset().top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777506/offsettop-vs-jquery-offset-top)